# Embedding Cocos2d into another Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am wanting to embed a game that I created in Cocos2d into a standard project. I am at a lose of where to start. I am sure there will be a conflict with having 2 AppDelagate files and 2 RootViewController files together. In the end I would like to be able to have a button that starts the Cocos2d project as if it was a stand-alone project minus having an exit button that returns back to the main project.

Comment: What do you mean 'embed'? Cocos2d is OpenGL based, while a master-detail application is UIKit based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be easier than I thought. A cocos2d project acts just like a UIView for the most part so you can transition to it like a normal view.